# fusioncharts and wkhtmltoimage

Tags: php, fusioncharts, wkhtmltoimage

I'm trying to export fusionChart Images on the Server Without Rendering in a Browser.. i would like to use the image in tcpdf

i followed the example here
http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/

```
    < ?php
    $webpageURLWithChart = "mychart.php";
    $outputImageFileName = "savedImage.png";
    $delay = 500;
    $shellout = shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage --javascript-delay $delay $webpageURLWithChart $outputImageFileName" );
    echo $shellout;
    ?>
```

mychart.php is working fine but image is not generated

path is set C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf

any help is much apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep images and files inside your project folder and give the source names correctly.

Comment: all are set in D:\wamp\www\test\

Comment: echo the image path and manually go through the path or using a browser check whether the image path is correct.

Comment: Thank you Finally Got it..we have to set the full url for $webpageURLWithChart.. i posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got it..we have to set the full url for $webpageURLWithChart

```
  < ?php
    $webpageURLWithChart = "http://localhost/test/mychart.php";
    $outputImageFileName = "savedImage.png";
    $delay = 500;
    $shellout = shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage --javascript-delay $delay $webpageURLWithChart $outputImageFileName" );
    echo $shellout;
    ?>
```